# shell script replace only first string in variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a variable `${value}` and its contents are:

```
bigint_col, smallint_col,string_col,string_col,string_col, bigint_col, string_col,string_col,timestamp_col,timestamp_col,timestamp_col,timestamp_col
```

I want to replace only first `bigint_col` with `my_col` from the variable itself so that the new contents should look like this

```
my_col, smallint_col,string_col,string_col,string_col, bigint_col, string_col,string_col,timestamp_col,timestamp_col,timestamp_col,timestamp_col
```

I am looking some help to solve this.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "my_col,${value#*,}"`...

Comment: `echo "${value//bigint_col/my_col}"` outputs contents of `$value` replacing all instances of `bigint_col` with `my_col`.  To replace only the first instance, use `${value/bigint_col/my_col}`.

Comment: updated the question as per my desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "${value/bigint_col/my_col}"  # outputs contents of $value replacing the first instance of 'bigint_col' with 'my_col'
```